# doctrine - how to see what queries WOULD run on flush

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

I'm debugging a rather complex problem that happens only in a particular case (for sake of argument lets say one in 10000). I managed to isolate one case but if I execute the code db will change and I would only have one shot to find the issue.

I can ofc make a snapshot of the current state and revert to it then run it again (can't use transaction because there are some MyISAM tables and one alter somewhere in there). But that is time-consuming and to be fair a bit frustrating.

So the best solution for me would be to get the list of queries that would be executed and stop script there (in theory I should be able to get those from the unit of work but can't find how).

So... how can I get the list of queries that WOULD run?

Comment: Have you considered using EXPLAIN? Or. if you just want an output of the prepared statements, in doctrine you can use ```$q->getSql()``` and for the parameters ```$q->getParameters()```

Comment: There are hundreds of changes on multiple entities, if that was a query builder that would've been trivial.

Comment: If you know there is a 1 in 10,000 updates that is breaking in some way you could analyse the database' query log and isolate the entity that is problematic?

Comment: There's no such thing as a list of queries that WOULD run, because that would be fortune telling. There may be only a list of queries that DID run.

Answer (score 1):

I think the SQLLogger is what you are looking for. This logs all queries executed by Doctrine during a request to a response/file/whatever.

https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.5/Doctrine/DBAL/Logging/SQLLogger.html

The queries would, however, be executed on the database. So you will need to make a backup of your database and run it again, but at least you'll have a list of SQL queries to debug instead of a 'black box' situation.